# Using jsonlite to interact with Spotify API in R

Tags: r, api, spotify-app

I am trying to extract Spotify data via the API 
Using the below `getAlbums` Function:

```
getAlbums <- function(id,type="album",market="US") {
  total <- jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0("https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/",id,"/albums??&album_type=album"))$total
  req <- jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0("https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/",id,"/albums??offset=0&limit=",total,"&album_type=",type,"&market=",market))
  return(req$items[,c("id","name","album_type","available_markets")])
}
```

I am getting the below error:

```
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 400 Extracting Spotify Data
```

whereas i can successfully Authenticate for other parameters.

Comment: What is the Spotify artist ID you are attempting to use? I just tested this with one ("63MQldklfxkjYDoUE4Tppz") and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I tried for "3Q149ZH46Z0f3oDR7vlDYV" and it gave me error

Comment: Are you sure that is a valid artist ID? I tried looking it up (e.g. https://play.spotify.com/artist/3Q149ZH46Z0f3oDR7vlDYV) but it is not found.

Comment: I tried for Id 5K4W6rqBFWDnAN6FQUkS6x (Kanye West) and it works , Unsure why the other id dint work

Comment: Thanks Keith , i believe i wasn't using the correct id

Comment: No problem. It's easy to make these kinds of mistakes ;)